# Iterating over years in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, key

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d={"01-01-1948":[0,51,31],"01-02-1948":[1,53,31],"01-01-1949":[0.25,52,46],"01-02-1949":[0,50,32]}
```

The keys are date objects. I want to create another dictionary which will show me the total of value for each year like below

```
c={1948:[1,104,62],1949:[0.25,102,78]
```

Please tell me how I can do it. I am a beginner so don't show me in lambda numpy or in other topics which are not for beginners.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow it is expected that you post what you have tried so far.

Comment: So you want to make a year as a key?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of your problem:

```
import datetime

d={"01-01-1948":[0,51,31],"01-02-1948":[1,53,31],"01-01-1949":[0.25,52,46],"01-02-1949":[0,50,32]}

keys = d.keys()
new_d = {}

for t_date in keys:
    # parse it into date and get the year
    year = datetime.datetime.strptime(t_date, '%d-%m-%Y').year
    if year in new_d:
        # if year exists then add numbers together
        for i in range(len(new_d[year])):
            new_d[year][i] += d[t_date][i]
    else:
        # does not exist so get values from the first occurence
        new_d[year] = d[t_date]
                       
print(new_d)
```

First, you need to convert your string into `datetime` object from python. Then you create a new empty dictionary which will contain the year and the sum of the years. You iterate through all years from the original dictionary and sum values if it exists in the new dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [286]: d
Out[286]:
{'01-01-1948': [0, 51, 31],
 '01-02-1948': [1, 53, 31],
 '01-01-1949': [0.25, 52, 46],
 '01-02-1949': [0, 50, 32]}

In [287]: unique_years = list(set([x.split('-')[-1] for x in d.keys()]))

In [288]: desired_output = {}

In [289]: for year in unique_years:
     desired_output[year] = [x for x in map(sum,zip(*[item[1] for item in d.items() if year in item[0]]))]

In [290]: desired_output
Out[290]: {'1949': [0.25, 102, 78], '1948': [1, 104, 62]}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new dictionary with *key* is year, *value* is [0, 0, 0]
- Traverses each element in the first dictionary, filter it year by year in the same way [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-substring-key-match-in-dictionary/) guides and add their values ​​to the new dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import add

key_list = defaultdict(list)
d = {"01-01-1948": [0, 51, 31], "01-02-1948": [1, 53, 31],
     "01-01-1949": [0.25, 52, 46], "01-02-1949": [0, 50, 32]}


just_year = [{x[-4:]: y} for x, y in d.items()]

for d in just_year:
    for t in d.items():
        key_list[t[0]].append(t[1])

l = [{k: list(map(add, *v))} for k, v in key_list.items()]

[{'1948': [1, 104, 62]}, {'1949': [0.25, 102, 78]}]
```